# how to use multiple dispatchers in same cherrypy application?

Tags: cherrypy, dispatcher

I have a cherrypy application like this:

```
import cherrypy
from controllers import UsersController

class Root(object):


    exposed = True

    def index(self):
        return 'welcome'


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Root()
    root.users = UsersController()

    cherrypy.tree.mount(
        root,
        '/',
        {
            '/users' :  {'request.dispatch' : cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher()}
        }
    )

cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

Now I wish to use MethodDispatcher() for providing REST api to /users resource and I want a default dispatcher for '/' path (where a call to root.index() is expected). Instead of writing own RoutesDispatcher() is there any way to achieve this? (e.g. using MethodDispatcher() for '/users' as shown and something like DefaultDispatcher() for '/')? BTW, the error I am getting is `'Root' object is not callable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `Root` is to be served with a normal dispatcher, it should be `index.exposed = True`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But I have a doubt, `exposed=True` exposes everything from class, including index(), right? Then why does default dispatcher not work like that? Am I missing on something very basic?

Comment: Got it. `The exposed=True` set on the class level is to make special methods (like __call__()) callable. In order to expose an object, one need to expose it's index() method. It's somewhat clear now, though not completely.