# "TypeError: object is not callable" using `cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher()`

Tags: python, cherrypy

I'm following along with the cherrypy tutorial ["Give it a REST"](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/tutorials.html#tutorial-7-give-us-a-rest), except I wanted to have my cherrypy server start two classes: One to serve some static files, and another one for the RESTful API:

api.py:

```
import cherrypy

class TestApi(object):
    conf = {
        '/api/v1/test': {
            'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
        }
    }
    exposed = True

    def GET(self):
        return "Test GET!"
```

server.py:

```
import cherrypy

import api

server_conf = {
    'server.socket_port': 1313,
}


class Root(object):
    conf = {
        '/': {
            'tools.staticdir.on': True,
            'tools.staticdir.dir': "/some/path",
            'tools.staticdir.debug': True
        }
    }

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return "Hello world!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.config.update(server_conf)
    cherrypy.tree.mount(Root(), '/', Root.conf)

    cherrypy.tree.mount(api.TestApi(), '/api/v1/test',
                        api.TestApi.conf)
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
```

However, when I start the server (`python server.py`) and do a GET on `http://localhost:1313/api/v1/test` I get this error:

> 500 Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from
>   fulfilling the request.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line
>   670, in respond
>       response.body = self.handler()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py",
>   line 217, in **call**
>       self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line
>   68, in **call**
>       raise x TypeError: 'TestApi' object is not callable

I looked up similar questions and came upon 
[how to use multiple dispatchers in same cherrypy application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965661/how-to-use-multiple-dispatchers-in-same-cherrypy-application), but it's not clear if the answer there is really applicable to me.  Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just realized the issue is with the TestApi.conf:

Need to change the path for the config from `'/api/v1/test'` to `'/'` in the section below.

```
class TestApi(object):
    conf = {
        '/api/v1/test': {
            'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
        }
    }
```

I guess this is because I already pass in the mount path in `server.py` so the config path is relative from that point on.

Comment: Yes, that's the same issue as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34753017/298371